# Dropdown menu with fallback to on hover, work on more than one menu item

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, onclick, hover

Been trying to get it so that I have a dropdown menu dropdown on click,
and if you do not have javascript enabled, so it uses regular mouseover.

However, I can not get it to work on more than one menu item, so that it is now so click on a menu, so go all down with the same content.

What am I doing wrong? See the example below.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/realitylab/H3KRk][1]
```

Comment: You have right. JavaScript not java :)